# How to use 32 bit variable for 16 bit TIMER register?

Tags: timer, embedded, 16-bit, isr

If one need to write a function that takes, as an argument a 32 bit variable and assigns it to 16 bit TIMER register (the embedded target have 16 bit resolution timer and we need to deal with 32 bit values to increase the resolution of the timer interrupt) - how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 16 bit timer to trigger an interrupt that uses a 16 bit software counter. Increment this every interrupt. When it overflows, or hit your target count you can set a flag for the main program loop to do something.

Comment: This does not change the _resolution_, it changes the maximum time. The OP is asking how "to increase the resolution of the timer interrupt", which cannot be done through software.

Comment: It depends on how you define resolution. If you talk about a counters bit depth then my solution works. Timers are related to the clock. The clock increments the timer counter and rolls over when the maximum value is reached. 32 bit timers rolls over at 2^32-1, 16 bit timers rolls over at 2^16-1. 16 bit timers cover less time than 32 bit ones do because they have fewer counts. To increase time resolution you need to increase the clock speed rather that counter bit depth.

Comment: When speaking of a timer, resolution is most definitely defined as time resolution - the length of a timer tick. It is not really open for interpretation.

Comment: The OP talks about 32 bit and 16 bit timers, how does that change the time resolution? It may be the basis of the confusion that he uses the word 'resolution' while he probably means bit depth of the counter. In a PIC24 you can combine two 16 bit timers to make a 32 bit one for example, but it doesn't change time resolution.

Comment: It doesn't, my point is that the question doesn't make much sense to begin with. We shouldn't guess what they mean, if the question is unclear it should be put on hold until clarified.

Comment: Agreed. Either way, both interpretations have been covered by our answers :)

Comment: I agree that my question is a little bit confusing when using the term resolution - I meant that we can get more accurate timer results by manipulating 16 bit timer using 32 bit value - can this be done and how?

Comment: @imqqmi: You confuse resolution and range/max. period duration.

Comment: @ItzikChaimov: How would that work? Any idea? No offence, but do you really understand how a timer module works?

Comment: Hi Olaf. Basically timer is a counter (up / down) which send an ISR when value set to maximum / zero. Counting rate (resolution) depends with system tick time/period.

Comment: @Itzik Chaimov: More accurate how? More accurate in longer duration or more accurate in short duration? If you want to reduce the time for each timer increment you'll need either a higher clock speed or use a CTMU module if available.

Comment: OK - so the question will be revised to just using a 32 bit value for a 16 bit TIMER counter - the answer of @imqqmi was very helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> to increase the resolution of the timer interrupt

You cannot increase the *resolution*, it is 16 bits and the timer hardware pre-scaler sets the resolution limits.

You should perhaps get better *accuracy* though, by changing the quality of the clock source oscillator.